# (C++) Invoking base operator from derived class operator

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

What's the correct way to invoke an operator from within the derived class's operator?

I'm trying to call a base overloaded operator from within the derived class's overloaded operator. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
const myObject& myObject::operator = (const myObject &otherObject) {
static_cast<BaseType>(*this) = static_cast<BaseType>(otherObject); // assuming BaseType has assignment overloaded
return *this;
}
```

This is the actual code:

```
const studentType& studentType::operator = (const studentType &student) {
  static_cast<personType>(*this) = static_cast<personType>(student);

  // new junk here

  return *this;
}
```

Note: The base class's operator is overloaded, so no issues there.

Comment: you probably mean `overridden` not `overloaded`

Comment: as far as I'm concerned, it's considered overloaded when the routine has multiple definitions, each with differing parameters.

Comment: The `static_cast` approach should work but you have to cast to *reference* to base type, not the base type itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
const studentType& studentType::operator = (const studentType &student) {
  personType::operator =(student);

  // new junk here

  return *this;
}
```

Comment: Yep, it worked, and surprisingly it makes lots of sense since operator= is just another function/method/routine. Thanks.